# Storybook HTML build failed due to mini-css-extract-plugin error

Tags: javascript, webpack, storybook

I am new to storybook and I am trying to build the storybook but I am receving the error related to the mini css extract plugin, this same code is being used in the other project and is working fine but not in here. How can I resolve this particular issue:

```
ERR! => Failed to build the preview
ERR! ./src/styles/styles.scss
ERR! Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ERR! Error: You forgot to add 'mini-css-extract-plugin' plugin (i.e. `{ plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()] }`), please read https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#getting-started
ERR!     at Object.pitch (C:\Users\atoms-design-system\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:51:14)
ERR!  @ ./.storybook/preview.js 1:0-35
ERR!  @ ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js
```

My storybook Preview.js:

```
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
    expanded : true
  },
}
```

Main.js:

```
const myWebpackConfig = require('../config/webpack.config')
const loaders = require('../config/webpack.loaders')

const sassLoader = loaders.find(loader => loader.test.test('.scss'))

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/html",
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push(sassLoader)
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      ...myWebpackConfig.resolve.alias,
    }

    return config
  },
}
```

webpack config.js (some sample part of code)

```
const plugins = require('./webpack.plugins');

module.exports = {
context: path.join(config.root, config.paths.src),
  entry: entries,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(config.root, config.paths.src, config.paths.components),
      '@scripts': path.resolve(config.root, config.paths.src, 'scripts'),
      '@images': path.resolve(config.root, config.paths.src, 'images'),
      '@fonts': path.resolve(config.root, config.paths.src, 'fonts'),
    },
  },
plugins,
}
```

webpack plugin

```
const cssExtract = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: `[name].${config.hash.styles ? '[contenthash].' : ''}css`,
});
module.exports = [
  ...
  cssExtract,
  ... 
].filter(Boolean);
```